# How to get rows as Arrays (not Hashes) in Sequel ORM?

Tags: ruby, sequel

In the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/) ORM for Ruby, the `Dataset` class has an `all` method which produces an Array of row hashes: each row is a Hash with column names as keys.

For example, given a table T:

```
a  b   c
--------------
0  22  "Abe"
1  35  "Betty"
2  58  "Chris"
```

then:

```
ds = DB['select a, b, c from T']
ah = ds.all # Array of row Hashes
```

should produce:

```
[{"a":0,"b":22,"c":"Abe"},{"a":1,"b":35,"c":"Betty"},{"a":2,"b":58,"c":"Chris"}]
```

Is there a way built in to Sequel to instead produce an Array of row Arrays, where each row is an array of only the values in each row *in the order specified in the query*?  Sort of how `select_rows` works in ActiveRecord?  Something like this:

```
aa = ds.rows # Array of row Arrays
```

which would produce:

```
[[0,22,"Abe"],[1,35,"Betty"],[2,58,"Chris"]]
```

Note: the expression:

```
aa = ds.map { |h| h.values }
```

produces an array of arrays, but the order of values in the rows is NOT guaranteed to match the order requested in the original query.  In this example, `aa` might look like:

```
[["Abe",0,22],["Betty",1,35],["Chris",2,58]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want just an array of array of values...

```
DB['select * from T'].map { |h| h.values }
```

seems to work

UPDATE given the updated requirement of the column order matching the query order...

```
cols= [:a, :c, :b]
DB[:T].select{cols}.collect{ |h| cols.collect {|c| h[c]}}
```

not very pretty but guaranteed order is the same as the select order.
There does not appear to be a builtin to do this. 
You could make a request for the feature.

Comment: This creates an array but unlike ActiveRecord `select_rows`, the order of the columns does not necessarily match the order requested in the underlying query.  I will edit my question to indicate this requirement.

Comment: I think if you want to guarantee the order then you need to specify the columns you want to fetch in order using `dataset#select{[columns,..]}`, I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: FYI, this will of course fail if you have duplicate column names in your result set: `DB['SELECT 1 AS test, 2 AS test']`

Answer (score 10):

Old versions of Sequel (pre 2.0) had the ability in some adapters to return arrays instead of hashes.  But it caused numerous issues, nobody used it, and I didn't want to maintain it, so it was removed.  If you really want arrays, you need to drop down to the connection level and use a connection specific method:

```
DB.synchronize do |conn|
  rows = conn.exec('SQL Here') # Hypothetical example code
end
```

The actual code you need will depend on the adapter you are using.

Comment: @jwfeam: I second that. I can't wipe the smile off of my face ever since I've discovered it. *Finally* something that lets me write exactly the query I need without concatenate bits and pieces of SQL strings.

Answer (score 6):

DB[:table].where().select_map(:id)

Comment: Should be accepted answer.
`my_keys = [:a, :b, :c];
DB[:T].select_map(my_keys)`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet found a built-in method to return an array of row arrays where the values in the row arrays are ordered by the column order in the original query.  The following function does* although I suspect an internal method could be more effecient:

```
def rows( ds )
  ret = []
  column_keys = ds.columns  # guaranteed to match query order?
  ds.all { |row_hash|
    row_array = []
    column_keys.map { |column_key| row_array << row_hash[column_key] }
    ret << row_array
  }
  ret
end
```

*This function depends on the order of the array returned by `Dataset.columns`.  If this order is undefined, then this `rows` function isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
ds = DB['select a, b, c from T'].to_a
```

not sure it it works but give it a shot.